# Existence of holomorphic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

The theorem below is discussed in the book 'Selected Problems on Exceptional Sets' written by Carleson (page 73) but I would like to generalize it to certain subharmonic functions.

Theorem : 
 Let $E\subset\mathbb C$ be a compact polar set, $D=\mathbb C\setminus E$ and $f\in\mathcal O(D)$ be holomorphic. If $$\int_D |f|^2 dxdy < \infty \mbox{ then } f\equiv 0.$$

Can anyone help me with a detailed proof or some references that may help me to find a detailed proof of the theorem? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @anyone: I don't know about potential theory; Wikipedia says that a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is polar. Is it really the case?

Comment: Yes, countable sets are polar

Comment: @Kara: sorry for my ignorance, but.. this means there is a subharmonic function on $\mathbb R$ that has constant value $-\infty$ on exactly, say, the rational numbers?

Comment: @Qfwfq: dimension must be at least 2. (In terms of classical potential theory, the log potential on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the Newton potential on $\mathbb{R}^3$ are singular at the origin. What would be the potential in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $|x|$ and is not singular at the origin.)

Comment: @WillieWong: yeah but my (uninformed) perplexity was about a subharmonic function having poles on a dense (countable) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was just wondering how such a function could be constructed, and even what it meant for a discontinuous function to be subharmonic (maybe in distribution sense?)

Comment: @Qfwfq: I'm actually puzzling through that right now. Looking at Doob's book on Potential Theory, he asserts first that "countable sets are polar"; but this is followed by (I paraphrase)  "suppose $A$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $u$ a subharmonic function equalling $-\infty$ on $A$... the set of infinities of $u$ is polar dense $G_\delta$ and  therefore not countable."

Comment: For what it is worth, given any polar set $A$ and any $\xi\not\in A$, Doob can construct a non-constant subharmonic function that equals $-\infty$ on $A$ and is finite on $\xi$. He doesn't claim anything about constructing a function that is infinite precisely on $A$. // A comment on the [EoM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Polar_set) suggests that there may be confusion between "complete polar set" versus "polar set" in the various definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove that if $u\geq0$ is subharmonic on $D$ with $\int_D u(z) dx\,dy<\infty$, then $u=0$ on $D$.

Let $\phi$ be a subharmonic function such, that $\phi|_E=-\infty$.
Let $M=\int_D u(z) dx\,dy$. Consider $u_\epsilon = u+\epsilon\phi$ for $\epsilon>0$. Those functions are subharmonic on $\mathbb{C}$. Choose $w\in D$. Pick $\delta>0$ and choose $R$ such that $\pi R^2>2M/\delta$. Let $B_R(w)$ be a disk with the center at $w$ and the radius $R$. Let $\epsilon_0>0$ be so small that $\epsilon_0 \int_{B_R(w)} \phi(z)dx\,dy<M$. Then for $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ we have $\int_{B_R(w)}u_\epsilon dx\,dy<2M$, thus
$$u_\epsilon (w)\leq \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int_{B_R(w)} u_\epsilon(z) dx\,dw<\delta\;.$$ 
This imply that $u(w)\leq \delta$.

This proof obviously works for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ Oleg Eroshkin: Why $u_{\epsilon}$ are subharmonic on $\mathbb C$? Observe that we may have $\limsup u_{\epsilon}=+\infty$ on $E.$

Comment: That's a good point. I will think about it when I will have time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this proof in a book but I did not understand the inequalities. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Let $D_1\subset D_2\subset\cdots\subset D,$ where $D_m$ is bounded by a finite number of analytic curves. Let $g_m$ be the Green's function of $D_m$  with pole at $\infty$ and let $h_m$ be its conjugate function. it is well known  that $E$ is polar means $g_m(z)$  converges uniformly to $\infty,$ $z\in D,$  on inside domains. Hence if we introduce the coordinates $\zeta=\xi+\eta=g_m+i h_m$ in $D_m$ and   consider the domain $\Omega_m=\{z, 0<g_m<1\}$ we have for $f\in H^2(D),$  $$\int\int_{\Omega_m}|f(z)|^2dxdy=\int_0^1d\xi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|f|^2d\eta}{(\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial n})^2}=\epsilon_m\rightarrow 0,$$
 On the other hand, the following estimate holds :

$$\int_0^1d\xi\left(\int_{g_m=\xi}|f(z)||dz|\right)^2\leq\int_0^1d\xi\left\{\int_{g_m=\xi}\frac{\partial g_v}{\partial n}|dz|.\int_{g_m=\xi}\frac{|f|^2}{\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial n}}|dz|\right\}$$
 $$=2\pi\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|f|^2}{(\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial n})^2}d\eta d\xi=2\pi\epsilon_m.$$

Hence $\xi_m,$ $0<\xi_m<1,$ exists so that $$  \int_{g_m=\xi_m}|f(z)||dz|\leq \sqrt{2\pi\epsilon_m}  $$

The curves $g_m=\xi_m$ approach $E$ uniformly as $m\rightarrow \infty.$ Let $z_0$ be fixed in $D.$ Then for $m>m_0$ since  $f(\infty)=0$ $$|f(z_0)|=|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{g_m=\xi_m}\frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}|\leq const. \sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}\rightarrow 0.$$ This implies $f(z)\equiv 0$ and concludes the proof.